# Is it possible for a website to heat up a android Device and cause faster battery draining?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I am developing a website which is a Single Page Application (built on AngularJS).

However, my client complains that using the website is causing user devices to heat up and drains the battery faster.

Technologies used for the development.

For back-end 
- PHP / Codeigniter

For front-end
 - Angular JS

I have a lot of codes written in native Javascript too.

Is it possible for a website to cause these issues? If yes, how can I solve this?

Comment: yes, the more work your website makes the phone do the hotter it will get and the more battery it will use

Comment: The question of "what to do" is way too broad for useful answers.

Comment: AngularJS itself is enough :)

Comment: Make sure to remove any event listeners when they are no longer needed. If you don’t clean up event listeners and they get applied multiple times, this will cause memory leaks and slow down the device.

Comment: Recent versions of Opera include a crypto mining blocker, which shows that  doing expensive work is certainly possible. See https://cryptojackingtest.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Poorly coded JavaScript can cause the browser to use more resources and hence  device heats up or the battery drains faster.

Things to look for:  Network calls , Unnecessary event listeners (touch , scroll), Expensive animations  etc.

How to solve:
Try to remove some animations and event listeners  which cause lag to the web-app , those might be the ones using the most of the resources. This way you need to filter our the culprit code and optimise it.

You can refer to this BBC article for a detailed report on this : http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-17811557

Comment: please include essential parts of the article in your answer as it may be removed in the future

Comment: I don't think that "poorly coded javascript" is sufficient hint for op, that's why I asked you to provide more details :)

Answer (score 9):

There are many factors, for example:

- Animations causing multiple repaints
- If you have many watchers, frequent updates will cause a lot of work to perform digest cycles
- Maintaining TCP connection is also very costly, so if you query your backend server for live data it will hurt on mobile (another example is collecting analytics data like clicks and sending them immediately to the server)

Fixes for this cases would be to reduce number of watchers and perform updates less frequently on mobile. Updates like those from analytics should be send in batches.

There is no solution that would apply to every case, if you want to save your customer's battery you can profile your application, see what parts of code are expensive and decide if they are necessary to perform on mobile devices.

And one important thing - **verify yourself that it is your application causing the drains**, because it may be something different and you would be wasting your time trying to optimize something that works ok.

Comment: You might want to mention that keeping connections open is actually hard on the RF peripherals, not the CPU itself. (But either way, it drains battery and produces heat)

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: yes, it is possible.
When developing, you can pick two ways to handle calculations:

- you can process them locally, on the server-side
- you can process themremotely by pushing them to the client-side

The latter, mostly when poorly coded, can genereate high and constant CPU usage on the client-side, thus resulting in a hot device and quickly drained battery.